# HTML, WordPress and JS - using iFrame and full height document: the iframe go above the elements

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

I'm working on new self-website and self WordPress theme but i have a problem.

I'm tring to embed my gallery website into a wordpress page and the iframe showing up above the elements like it stuck.
using Lychee Gallery (https://lychee.electerious.com/) and this code to embed and take the height of the iframe:

```
<script>
function setHeight() {
parent.document.getElementById('iframemanga').style.height = 
document['body'].offsetHeight + 'px';
}
</script>

<style>
iframe {
width:100%;
}
</style>

<iframe id="iframemanga" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
onload="setHeight()" src="http://localhost/m/"> </iframe>
```

The iFrame is real works but above the site itself.

Example about what I'm talking
[image: Example about what i'm talking]
Example about what I'm talking
[image: Example about what i'm talking 2]

Comment: looks like your iframe have `position: absolute` rule. provide all related css of your iframe. get them from developers console

Comment: Already checked the position rule and it does nothing... can't find the issue, changing to    relative does not affect.

Comment: its a bit hard to guess what may be an issue. can you provide url of that page?

Comment: hmm... i can't send because this is on my localhost not on air...

Comment: whats about providing all html markup related to `iframe`( <iframe>, parents ) and all css rules related to them?

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the help bud! i got into a solution. the problem was in the display and position rules of the main containers.